# Compile cyanoboot: No rule to make target

Tags: c++, cygwin, u-boot

I'm trying to compile the cyanoboot project found [here](https://github.com/CMNookTablet/acclaim_cyanoboot). I have no experience with c++ compiling but I've followed the read-me and seem to have hit a brick wall. I've extracted the downloaded source files and navigated to them in cygwin, I then run the command:

```
make clean
```

which looks like it is successful. After that I run

```
make omap4430sdp_config
```

which also seems to work but doesn't create any files(not sure if it should?). Then, when I run the final make command I get the error:

```
makefile:98: /cygdrive/c/cyanoboot/config.mk: No such file or directory 
make: *** No rule to make target `/cygdrive/c/cyanoboot/config.mk'.  Stop.
```

This config.mk file definitely does exist, you can see it at the git hub link above and I haven't changed any files. I've been struggling with this for a few hours now and I just cant figure it out. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package is new to me. But, there are multiple processors supported, for example i386/m68k/arm. Therefore you will likely need environment set up properly, for example ARCH=arm and CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-

To check if make config worked, you can look for modified or new files. Doing it myself, here you see a link has been added:
~/cmn/CMNookTablet-acclaim_cyanoboot-02c6247$ find . | xargs ls -alt | more
lrwxrwxrwx   1 joe joe       7 Oct 24 10:03 ./include/asm -> asm-arm
...

I tried your build with my toolchain, got this FWIW

...
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g  -Os   -fno-strict-aliasing  -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float  -D_*KERNEL*_ -DTEXT_BASE=0x80e80000 -I/home/joe/cmn/CMNookTablet-acclaim_cyanoboot-02c6247/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/include -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D_*ARM*_ -march=armv7-a -mabi=apcs-gnu -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -c -o hal_services.o hal_services.c

{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:276: Error: selected processor does not support Thumb mode `smc #0'

make[1]: *** [hal_services.o] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joe/cmn/CMNookTablet-acclaim_cyanoboot-02c6247/board/omap4430sdp'

make: *** [board/omap4430sdp/libomap4430sdp.a] Error 2